# C reading from file: Reading only first char of line

Tags: c

I have to get node ids from DIMES ASNodes.csv (http://netdimes.org/new/?q=node/65) files. 
File looks like this:

```
6067,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 10:03:53.0,2007-01-02 02:54:13.0,12,6,0
29287,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 21:11:07.0,2007-01-02 07:33:35.0,1,0,0
...
```

So far I came up with this code, but it doesn't work quite right. Althought it prints out all the numbers I needed, it also prints out the node id twice and sometimes prints zeroes in between. Thanks for any ideas

```
void loadNodes(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* nodes = fopen(filename, "r");

    unsigned int id = 0;
    char line[64];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), nodes) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%u%*[^\n]", &id);
        printf("id = %u\n", id);
    }
    fclose(nodes);
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdemM.png)

Comment: You are supposed to provide all information **in the question itself**. Not just as links. And post text **as text**.

Comment: The `csv` doesn't just have numbers. If the csv has pre-defined format, you probably should read the entire line using `sscanf` and use format specifiers to capture each column individually.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble is that your lines have 63 characters plus a newline, which means that the `fgets()` reads up to, but not including, the newline (and you process that and get the correct number), then the next `fgets()` reads the newline that was left behind on the previous input (and you process that — it is surprising that you get zeros rather than a repeat of the previous number).

Here's your code converted into an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) `main()` program that reads from standard input (which saves me from having to validate, open and close files):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned id = 0;
    char line[64];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Line: [%s]\n", line);
        sscanf(line,"%u", &id);
        printf("id = %u\n", id);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the diagnostic printing of the line just read.  The code should really check the return value from `sscanf()`.  (There was no virtue in skipping the trailing debris, so I removed that from the format string.)

Given the data file (`data`):

```
6067,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 10:03:53.0,2007-01-02 02:54:13.0,12,6,0
29287,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 21:11:07.0,2007-01-02 07:33:35.0,1,0,0
```

The output I get from `so.37103830 < data` is:

```
Line: [6067,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 10:03:53.0,2007-01-02 02:54:13.0,12,6,0]
id = 6067
Line: [
]
id = 6067
Line: [29287,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 21:11:07.0,2007-01-02 07:33:35.0,1,0,0]
id = 29287
Line: [
]
id = 29287
```

#### Avoiding the problem

The simplest fix is to use a longer buffer length; I normally use 4096 when I don't care about what happens if a really long line is read, but you might decide that 128 or 256 is sufficient.

Otherwise, I use POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which will read arbitrarily long lines (subject to not running out of memory).

With a longer line length, I get the output:

```
Line: [6067,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 10:03:53.0,2007-01-02 02:54:13.0,12,6,0
]
id = 6067
Line: [29287,UNKNOWN,2007-02-03 21:11:07.0,2007-01-02 07:33:35.0,1,0,0
]
id = 29287
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need the first column from the file (since you mention node ids), you could use:

```
unsigned int node_id;
char str[100];
while(scanf("%u,%[^\n]",&node_id, str) == 2) {
    printf("%u\n",node_id);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/lMIEus)

Comment: This code can invoke undefined behaviour due to buffer overflow! Bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks for pointing out. Were you talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much, just changed 'scanf' to 'fscanf' and it seems to work as it should. @Olaf where can you get buffer overflow?

Comment: @MukulGupta: I don't see `feof` in your answer. So it is apparently not.

Comment: @ZoloDobyvateľ: What if the input line is too long?

Comment: There wasn't `feof` but before the edit, the `scanf` condition checked for EOF which is a bad practice. As for the input line being too long, I'd guess that OP knows the maximum length of a given line since he/she used `64` in his original question.

Comment: @Olaf: Right...I see. But in this case I think the line won't be too long.

Comment: @MukulGupta: While you are right this is bad practice, the `feof` issue is a completely different subject.

Comment: @ZoloDobyvateľ: That's what all programmers thought whose code now is entrance for all kind of malware. **Better safe than sorry!**